# Trigger error when converting to master detail

Tags: apex

We have custom object order management which was child object for account (look up field), some of the order management fields gets populated through trigger, but we recently changed the lookup to master detail and receiving error when creating new order file

Error: Execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: field is not writable: Order_Management__c.Account__c Trigger.UpdateQuoteAccOppty:line 69, column 1

Trigger updates account info from opp and opp and account info from Quote, so now since we changed it to master details, account is required field and how to modify the trigger so account info gets populated from opp before saving?

```
/*
######################################################################
Trigger Description: 
           Updates the Opportunity and account information from Quote
######################################################################
*/

trigger UpdateQuoteAccOppty on Order_Management__c (before insert, before update) {
 list<Order_Management__c>olist = new list<Order_Management__c>();
 list<Id>qId= new list<Id>();
 list<Id>oId = new list<id>();
 for(Order_Management__c o : Trigger.New)
  { 
   if(o.Oracle_Quote__c!=null)
    qId.add(o.Oracle_Quote__c);
   if((o.Opportunity__c!=null))
     oId.add(o.Opportunity__c);
  }
if(qId.size()>0){
 system.debug('-----------qId-----------'+qId); 
 list<cafsl__Oracle_Quote__c> bqlist = [Select b.cafsl__Opportunity__c,b.cafsl__Opportunity__r.Amount,b.cafsl__Opportunity__r.CurrencyIsoCode,b.cafsl__Opportunity__r.Owner.Name, b.cafsl__Opportunity__r.CloseDate, b.cafsl__Opportunity__r.AccountId, b.Id From cafsl__Oracle_Quote__c b where b.Id in:qId];
 system.debug('-----------bqlist-----------'+bqlist);
 map<Id,Id>QuoOppMap = new map<Id,Id>();
 map<Id,Id>QuoAccMap = new map<Id,Id>();
 map<Id,Decimal>QuoAmtMap = new map<id,Decimal>();
 map<Id,String>QuoOwnerMap = new map<Id,String>();
 map<Id,String>QuoCURmap = new map<Id,String>();
 map<Id,String>QuoSCmap = new map<Id,String>();
 for(cafsl__Oracle_Quote__c bq: bqlist){
    QuoOppMap.put(bq.id,bq.cafsl__Opportunity__c);
    QuoAccMap.put(bq.id,bq.cafsl__Opportunity__r.AccountId);
    QuoAmtMap.put(bq.id,bq.cafsl__Opportunity__r.Amount);
    QuoOwnerMap.put(bq.id,bq.cafsl__Opportunity__r.Owner.Name);
    QuoCURmap.put(bq.id,bq.cafsl__Opportunity__r.CurrencyIsoCode);
 // QuoSCmap.put(bq.id,bq.cafsl__Opportunity__r.Sales_Channel__c);
 }
 system.debug('-----------QuoOppMap-----------'+QuoOppMap);
 system.debug('-----------QuoAccMap-----------'+QuoAccMap);
 for(Order_Management__c o : Trigger.New){
    if(o.Oracle_Quote__c!=null){
    o.Opportunity__c = QuoOppMap.get(o.Oracle_Quote__c);
    o.Account__c =  QuoAccMap.get(o.Oracle_Quote__c);
    o.Amount__c =  QuoAmtMap.get(o.Oracle_Quote__c);
    o.Opp_Owner__c = QuoOwnerMap.get(o.Oracle_Quote__c);
    o.CurrencyIsoCode = QuoCURmap.get(o.Oracle_Quote__c);
 // o.Sales_Channel__c = QuoSCmap.get(o.Oracle_Quote__c);
   }
 }
}

if(oId.size()>0){
  
  list<Opportunity>opptylist = [Select o.Id,o.Amount,o.CurrencyIsoCode,o.AccountId, o.OwnerId, o.Owner.Name, o.CloseDate From Opportunity o where o.Id in: oId];  
  system.debug('----opptylist--'+opptylist);
  map<Id,Id>OppAccMap = new map<Id,Id>();
  map<Id,Decimal>OppAmtMap = new map<Id,Decimal>();
  map<Id,String>OppOwnerMap = new map<Id,String>();
  map<Id,String>OppCurMap = new map<Id,String>();
  map<Id,String>OppSCMap = new map<Id,String>();
  for(Opportunity o:opptylist){
    OppAccMap.put(o.Id,o.AccountId);
    OppAmtMap.put(o.Id,o.Amount);
    OppOwnerMap.put(o.Id,o.Owner.Name);
    OppCurMap.put(o.Id,o.CurrencyIsoCode);
 // OppSCMap.put(o.Id,o.Sales_Channel__c);
    system.debug('----OppSCMap---'+OppSCMap);
  }
  for(Order_Management__c o : Trigger.New){
     o.Account__c =  OppAccMap.get(o.Opportunity__c);
     o.Amount__c =  OppAmtMap.get(o.Opportunity__c);
     o.Opp_Owner__c = OppOwnerMap.get(o.Opportunity__c);
     o.CurrencyIsoCode = OppCurMap.get(o.Opportunity__c);
  // o.Sales_Channel__c = OppSCMap.get(o.Opportunity__c);

     }
 } 
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is the error message and which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Error: Execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: field is not writable: Order_Management__c.Account__c Trigger.UpdateQuoteAccOppty:line 69, column 1

Comment: Please always **[edit]** posts with any clarifications.

Comment: Did you allow reparenting when updating the field to MD?

Comment: Yes i did but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have forced our users to create record from account to overcome this issue

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you have not allowed reparenting on MD field config.

If you don't want reparenting, then you will need to remove line 69 in `update` context. Even if you pass the same ID, the error will still be there, from your perspective you are not changing anything but from SF perspective you are trying to write to a field which once set cannot be changed.

Comment: I tried reparenting but didn't work, i also removed line 69 but when i could not create Order management record since Account is required field now and it's not auto populating from Opportunity or Quote and couldn't save the record

Comment: Seems like you should read up on trigger best practice and move your code out of the trigger body, have per event handlers, and only set the MD field in `insert` context.

Comment: Is that's what causing the error?

Comment: Can you update the question with config of you master detail field (I am assuming it is Account__c), full screenshot and the error

Comment: Yes, Account__c is the masterdetail field, i updated the screenshot

Comment: I meant the field config. You can goto Setup > Objects Then open the field account on Order management object. It should should the details such as field name, API name, and other details. Something like this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSMBfY8isIYGLLyC8GixF4drNcbru7GGOp7Lw&usqp=CAU

Comment: @manjit5190 Added pic for the field config

Comment: @Admin_BA Lets continue this in the chat here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124836/trigger-error-when-converting-to-master-detail